# Как повесить focus на элемент внутри label?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста как повесить фокусировку на label а точнее на элемент который находиться всередине него. Приведу пример

```css
.bl_payment__label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bl_payment__label:focus {
  color: #ffd608;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.bl_payment__text {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bl_payment__text {
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #505050;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.bl_payment__text:hover {
  color: #ffd608;
}
.bl_payment__text:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #ffd608;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bl_payment__text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #505050;
}

.bl_delivery__label input:checked + .bl_delivery__text,
.bl_payment__label input:checked + .bl_payment__text {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffd608;
}
.bl_delivery__label input:checked + .bl_delivery__text:after,
.bl_payment__label input:checked + .bl_payment__text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -22px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ffc808;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<label class="bl_payment__label" tabindex="0">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="bl_payment__text">Оплата наличными</span>
</label>
<label class="bl_payment__label" tabindex="0">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="bl_payment__text">Банковский перевод</span>
</label>
```

как сделать так что б по этим radio кнопкам можно было передвигаться через Tab ? Допустим я хочу что б текст подсвечивался, и добавлялся правильный стиль по checked  при этом их можно б было активировать через Enter) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё оказалось ужасно банально. Оказывается работает на radio-кнопках своеобразно. "Чекается" он не Enter'ом, а пробелом. Перемещение внутри одной группы не Tab'ом, а стрелками.

```css
.bl_payment__label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bl_payment__label:focus {
  color: #ffd608;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bl_payment__text {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bl_payment__text {
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #505050;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.bl_payment__text:hover {
  color: #ffd608;
}
.bl_payment__text:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #ffd608;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bl_payment__text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #505050;
}

.bl_delivery__label input:checked + .bl_delivery__text,
.bl_payment__label input:checked + .bl_payment__text {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffd608;
}
.bl_delivery__label input:checked + .bl_delivery__text:after,
.bl_payment__label input:checked + .bl_payment__text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -22px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ffc808;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<label class="bl_payment__label">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment" tabindex="0">
  <span class="bl_payment__text" tabindex="0">Оплата наличными</span>
</label>
<label class="bl_payment__label">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment" tabindex="0">
  <span class="bl_payment__text" tabindex="0">Банковский перевод</span>
</label>
```

Не понятно, зачем такое было реализовано, но за то теперь точно можно работать с элементами label без мыши если допустить что на них повешен tabindex="0"

Comment: `Space`, а не `Enter` используется что бы не допустить отправку формы. `Tab` и `Shift` + `Tab` перемещают по полям формы. Группа radio-селекторов это одно поле. Вы же не передвигаете курсор в input с помощью `Tab`. С точки зрения браузера, такое поведение более чем логично.

Answer (score 4):

Здравствуйте,но Вы же уже сделали возможность передвигаться добавив атрибут tabindex="0".Я думаю для текста задан .

```
bl_payment__text:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #ffd608;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Но у вас данный элемент фокус не получает,это можно посмотреть добавив tabindex="0":

```
<link href="stack.css" rel="stylesheet">
<label class="bl_payment__label" tabindex="0">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="bl_payment__text" tabindex="0">Оплата наличными</span>
</label>
<label class="bl_payment__label" tabindex="0">
  <input class="" type="radio" name="payment">
  <span class="bl_payment__text" tabindex="0">Банковский перевод</span>
</label>
```

Исправьте селектор:

```
.bl_payment__text:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #ffd608;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

на

```
.bl_payment__label:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.bl_payment__label:focus .bl_payment__text {
  color: #ffd608;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

А для enter воспользуйтесь js,событие keydown.

Comment: Необходим вариант полностью сохраняющий функциональность отображаемых элементов без использования мыши или тачпада при попадании фокуса на данный элемент. Вот допустим у меня на сайте таких радиокнопок >10 как узнать на какой сейчас фокус и какая сейчас имеет статус :checked ? Не знаю как ещё точнее раскрыть, что именно, я хочу получить в ответе...